# Microsoft Access 2013 Monthly Currency/County/Entity Bank Balanace Summary Merge

Tags: excel, ms-access, import, export

So I have created a database that has the table: `tblMonthlySummary`

That table links to three other tables: `tblCountry`, `tblFXRates`, and
`tblStaticBankDetails`.

There are three queries that are derived from those tables and their
relationships: `qrCountry`, `qrCurrency`, and `qrEntity`. Those queries produce
a closing balance summary based on their titles.

I have tried several times to import a new excel sheet into the existing table
`tblMonthlySummary` in order to produce updated queries on a monthly or even
daily basis.

In essecence, I want to be able to provide new data from future transaction
dates from the bank in order export updated queries for the day (or month).

What is the best way to do this? Fair warning I am fairly new to Access. But I
am open to any and all solutions, whatever is most efficient.

Comment: Access and Excel work great together. You can import spreadsheets to append to database tables either on the ribbon (External Data) or in code. One caveat is that the worksheet to be imported must be structured exactly like the table (column names, data types, etc.).

Comment: I have tried to append the database but it continue to give me errors saying none of the date has been imported successfully. The formatting is the same as well? Any solutions?

Comment: Check the `ImportErrors` table and be sure ENTIRE column in Excel is formatted to proper Date: `MM/DD/YYY HH:MM SS` or whatever is your regional setting (i.e, UK vs US). Don't just look at the column actually check cells' NumberFormat. Sometimes Excel uses custom date formats.